# sqlplus provide parameter to ACCEPT command

Tags: sqlplus

I have a sql script with an `accept` command in it, to prompt user for a variable.

From within SQL Plus, is there a way to run such a script and provide a parameter so that the prompt doesn't come up?

```
SQL > @testscript param
```

`testscript` contains something like

```
accept myvar prompt "Please insert a value"
```